# How to access session attributes in doIf block?

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to write the `gatling` test step which will do the retry based on some saved session values. How could I access the values in following `doIf` chain step?

```
val step = asLongAs(session => !session.contains("status") || session("status").as[Int] == 123) {
  exec(http("post")
   .post("/test")
   .check(status.saveAs("status"))
   .check(
     checkIf(session => session("status").as[Int] == 123) {
       jsonPath("$.data1").saveAs("data1")
       jsonPath("$.data2").saveAs("data2")
     }))
 .doIf(session => session("status").as[Int] == 123) {
    pause(data1, data2) // <------- use data here HERE
 }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly? What you're doing looks fine.

Comment: I'd like to use saved `"data"` value in the pause statement, e.g `pause(data)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```scala
.doIf(session => session("status").as[Int] == 123) {
  pause(
    session => {
      val data = session("data").as[String] // data is a String, not a FiniteDuration
      ??? // your job to return a FiniteDuration based on the data String
    },
    session => {
      val data = session("data").as[String] // data is a String, not a FiniteDuration
      ??? // your job to return a FiniteDuration based on the data String
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stéphane! But how would you incorporate it in the example from the question above? (I'm not sure how to merge it into `if` block) In addition, what if I want to put there two values (like `pause(a,b)`)?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but honestly, I don't get why you're struggling.

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: It works for me when I convert the attribute `session("data").as[Duration]` (answer edit suggested). But I still don't know how to use there two arguments to feed pause like `pause(a,b)` (I already updated question example).

Comment: suggested answer edit wrong and rejected, data is a String, casting it into a Duration would make code compile but crash at runtime.

Comment: "But I still don't know how to use there two arguments" This is getting tiring, you keep on changing your question. I'm done here.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, this one works for me perfectly! (answer accepted)